# How can I go about making map != null?

Tags: android-fragments, android-maps-v2, fragmenttransaction

I have the following code for an android fragment written here:

Java file:

```
package com.WolfDev.ExercisePlanner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

/**
 * Created by WolfDev on 4/14/2014.
 */
public class TrackerFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
//private boolean chronoRunning = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3_action, container, false);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.map, supportMapFragment).commit();
    activityBody();
    return rootView;
}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px"
          android:layout_weight="6"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
</fragment>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:text="@+id/chronometerDisplay"
            android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="START/STOP"
            android:id="@+id/btnStartStop"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LAP/RESET"
            android:id="@+id/btnLapReset"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the code, I have this line commented out:

```
//googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

When it is not commented out, I get a NullPointerException error. My research has shown me that it is occurring because the variable googleMap is null. How do I correct this so it is no longer null?

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot have

```
<fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight="6"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
```

in your fragment's layout file. Read [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

==> Use `FrameLayout` as a container for your map.

2) You cannot expect `SupportMapFragment.newInstance()` to immediately return `GoogleMap` instance. Transactions don't work that way.

==> Call `mapFragment.getMap()` in `onResume`.

Comment: Where are you getting the mapFragment from? I do not have a variable with that name.

Comment: @Patr3xion I guess you would want to assign `SupportMapFragment.newInstance()` to a field instead of local variable.